# No module named 'utils.google_utils'

Tags: python

я запускаю эту ячейку, скопированную  из другого google colab

у меня возникает ошибка

> No module named 'utils.google_utils'

```
!git clone https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5  # clone repo
!pip install -r yolov5/requirements.txt  # install dependencies (ignore errors)
%cd yolov5

import torch
from IPython.display import Image, clear_output  # to display images
from utils.google_utils import gdrive_download  # to download models/datasets


No module named 'utils.google_utils'
```

Comment: Ну да, в показанном вами репозитории google_utils был [переименован](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/commit/5d66e487236daf4cbf816704453d0cc4905ee463) два месяца назад

Comment: благодарю за помощь, я воспользовался вашей ссылкой и посмотрел изменения